# Define javascript array one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I would like to use something like (for using Chartist):

```
var chart[0] = new Chartist.Line('#stat1', data1, options);
var chart[1] = new Chartist.Line('#stat2', data2, options);
var chart[2] = new Chartist.Line('#stat3', data3, options);
var chart[3] = new Chartist.Line('#stat4', data4, options);
```

But the `chart[]` seems to be undefined. How can I make such array variables in a `for` loop in javascript in such a way that it would be defined and working?

**UPDATE:** I need this for ajax update of my 7 graphs. I have a

```
for (i=0; i<=7; i++)
    {
    var data = {
    labels: ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'maj', 'jun', 'jul', 'avg', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec'],
    series: [
    {
        data: one[i]
    }]
    }

    chart[i].update(data)
}
```

The chart function is not so important here, but I need to do the `chart[i].update(data)` that is why I need 7 variables that can be updated in `1for` loop.

Comment: i am not getting you

Comment: If you are not getting me I don't think I deserve a down vote.

Comment: believe me . i didn't .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it if anyone needs to know... Here is the whole function which includes answer to my question:

```
$('#year').on("change", function() {
    year=$(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'get',
        data:{year: year},
        success: function(text)
            {
                var one=text.split("|");

                for (i=0; i<=6; i++)
                {
                    var data = {
                    labels: ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'maj', 'jun', 'jul', 'avg', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec'],
                    series: [
                        {
                        name: 'number',
                        data: one[i].split(",")
                            }]
                    }
                 if (chart[i]) {
                     chart[i].update(data)
                 } else {
                    chart[i] = new Chartist.Line('#stat' + i, data, options);
                 }
                }
            }
    })  
})
```

From test.php I get something like:

```
7674,19972,6637,6378,8110,5068,5070,5871,5610,6439,4269|4,2,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,4,0|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0|12
,7,8,5,9,2,2,3,6,5,3|138,127,163,124,150,129,105,116,152,75,0|1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0|522,524,562,433,538
,422,350,392,529,292,36
```

Hope that helps anybody with Chartist and more importntly of how to look a javascript array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var chart = [];    
chart[0] = new Chartist.Line('#stat1', data1, options);
chart[1] = new Chartist.Line('#stat2', data2, options);
chart[2] = new Chartist.Line('#stat3', data3, options);
chart[3] = new Chartist.Line('#stat4', data4, options);
```

Comment: He asked *"How can I make such array variables in a for - next loop in javascript?"*, so he/she wants a for statement

Comment: Thanx, that works. If I could get that into a for-next loop it would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a second "data" variable inside the for loop and trying to use the previous one to assign a value to the second.